# 2d animation libgdx is not working

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, 2d

[My animation is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlNfR.png), only a static picture is displayed. I did everything according to the example from [libgdx/wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation). Why does not it work?

```
public class Thorns  extends GameObject implements IGameObject  {

    Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
    private static final int FRAME_COLS = 1, FRAME_ROWS = 2;
    public Thorns(Texture texture, Body body) {
        super(texture, body,false);
        Texture walkSheet = new Texture("Thorns.png");
        TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet,
            walkSheet.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS,
            walkSheet.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS);

        TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_ROWS*FRAME_COLS];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
                walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
            }
        }

        animation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(1.025f, walkFrames);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    int stateTime;

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
        stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        TextureRegion currentFrame = (TextureRegion) animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, false);

        spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, body.getTransform().getPosition().x, body.getTransform().getPosition().y);
        //drawSprite(spriteBatch);

    }
}
```

Animation does not start at all

Comment: Is your Thorns.png image 2 images side by side? Are you waiting 1.025 seconds to see the frame change? is it supposed to be non looping so it only shows the first image for 1.025 seconds?

Comment: As I understood the animation does not start at all. Everything is held on the first frame.
Looping changed to true, nothing changed.

Comment: I increased the frame change time by 10.0f, but nothing happens as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite possible animation is running but you're not getting his view, because you've two frame animation with frame duration `1.025 sec`. And your Animation is running **without loop**.

Try looped `Aniamation` so pass true as in second parameter of `getKeyFrame (float stateTime, boolean looping)` method.

```
@Override
public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    TextureRegion currentFrame =  animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, body.getTransform().getPosition().x, body.getTransform().getPosition().y);
}
```

**EDIT**

Change data type of `stateTime` to `float` from `int`.

Comment: Animation does not start at all. Everything is held on the first frame.
Looping changed to true, nothing changed

Comment: @GRbI3yH change data type of `stateTime` to `float`